# Rethinkdb filter on non-matching regular expression

Tags: regex, rethinkdb

I want to find documents that DO NOT match a specific regex pattern, but I do not see any support for that in re2--the regex library that rethinkdb uses (https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).  Also, I tried doing this with server-side javascript with `r.js()` but I can't seem to get the syntax right to extract the string I want to match against in a nested field where each key name is a string key.  I get undefined object errors on row["key"] as well as row.key in the following:

````
```
filter(r.js('(function(row){
 var re = /(?!(json|JSON))$/;
 return re.test(row.student_record.the_test);
})'))
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r.js` is a tool of last resort. Additionally, as far as I understand how JavaScript and RE2 work together, there should be a sort of binding via a specific object since `/.../` is standardized in JavaScript (if RethinkDB even provides any to the `r.js` context, and most likely `/.../` can never do what RE2 can do).

What about something like:

```
r.db('test')
  .table('test')
  .filter(doc =>
    doc.hasFields({'student_record': { 'the_test': true }})
      .and(doc('student_record')('the_test').match('(json|JSON)$').not())
  ) // matches all documents that have $.student_record.the_test not matching the regexp
```

or

```
r.db('test')
  .table('test')
  .filter(doc =>
    doc.hasFields({'student_record': { 'the_test': true }})
      .and(doc('student_record')('the_test').match('(json|JSON)$'))
      .not()
  ) // matches even documents that do not have $.student_record.the_test
```

?

- `doc.hasFields({'student_record': { 'the_test': true }})` - Verifies the JSON path to exist for a given document.
- `doc('student_record')('the_test').match('(json|JSON)$')` - Checks if `$.student_record.test` matches the regexp. By the way, are you probably looking for `'\\.(?:json|JSON)$'`? (See the escaped dot `\.` before the group).
- `not()` - Inverts the expression result.

Comment: I had to stare at your two solutions for a minute before I realized the second `.not()` is one paren level above the first `.not()`